# Calculating the accumulated area of an array of shapes

Tags: java, processing, println

I am trying to calculate the accumulating area for every creation of a rectangle.
I am aware of how to calculate the area for every time I create a rectangle, but I was hoping to get a running total.
Thanks!

```
float[] p1x = new float[0]; // hold the mouse pressed marks
float[] p1y = new float[0];
float[] p1z = new float[0];
float[] p2x = new float[0]; // hold the mouse pressed marks
float[] p2y = new float[0];
float[] p2z = new float[0];
int count = 0;

int rect_x1; // catch the start dragging point x
int rect_y1; // catch the start dragging point y
int rect_x2; // record  moving mouseX
int rect_y2; // record moving mouseY
int rect_z1; // record mouseX releasing point
int rect_z2; // record mouseY releasing point.

boolean press, release, drag, drawRect;

void setup() {
    smooth();
    size(600, 400);
    stroke(255);
    fill(255, 255, 255, 10);
}

void draw() {
    background(50);
    Rect();
}

void Rect() {

    float sizex = rect_x2 - rect_x1;
    float sizey = rect_y2 - rect_y1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        beginShape();
        vertex(p1x[i], p1y[i]);
        vertex(p2x[i], p1y[i]);
        vertex(p2x[i], p2y[i]);
        vertex(p1x[i], p2y[i]);
        endShape(CLOSE);
    }
    if (mousePressed && mouseButton == LEFT) {
        rect(rect_x1, rect_y1, sizex, sizey);
    }
}


void mousePressed() {
    p1x = append(p1x, mouseX);
    p1y = append(p1y, mouseY);
    rect_x1 = mouseX;
    rect_y1 = mouseY;
    mouseDragged(); // Reset vars

}

void mouseReleased() {
    p2x = append(p2x, mouseX);
    p2y = append(p2y, mouseY);
    rect_x2 = mouseX;
    rect_y2 = mouseY;
    count++;
}

void mouseDragged() {
    rect_x2 = mouseX;
    rect_y2 = mouseY;
}
```

Comment: If you indent the code to make it readable, I might actually look at it. Also, please read [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've got a couple options.

**Option 1:** Calculate the total every time you draw the rectangles. You've got a for loop in your `Rect()` function that loops through and draws them. You can just calculate the total area then.

**Option 2:** Keep a running total, and increment that every time you add a rectangle. You can do this in your `mouseReleased()` function.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you say you want one single accumulated number. You either have to total them up whenever you want the total, or you need to keep a running total and add to it whenever you add a new rectangle.

Comment: Sorry, when I referred to the single accumulated number, I meant the running total.

Comment: @TomMiller Then you just need to use a variable, and add the area of newly created rectangles to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still a little new with processing and still struggling with this. When I create the  new variable called area **area = ((rect_x2 - rect_x1) * (rect_y2 - rect_y1))** and place that under the for loop shouldn't the number be accumulating?

Comment: @TomMiller No, because you're just setting it equal to the newest rectangle. You aren't accumulating it anywhere. To accumulate it, you have to add the new value to the existing value: `area = area + ((rect_x2 - rect_x1) * (rect_y2 - rect_y1))` which can be shortened to `area += ((rect_x2 - rect_x1) * (rect_y2 - rect_y1))`

Comment: @TomMiller No problem. Gotta love moments like that. Btw you can find more info in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/addassign.html).